# difference between "hadn't met" vs "didn't meet"

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

Are there any differences between those sentences, and if yes what is that?

> Mrs. Potter was Mrs. Dursley's sister, but they **hadn't met** for several
>   years; in fact, Mrs. Dursley pretended she didn't have a sister,
>   because her sister and her good-for-nothing husband were as
>   unDursleyish as it was possible to be.
>
> Mrs. Potter was Mrs. Dursley's sister, but they **didn't meet** for several
>   years; in fact, Mrs. Dursley pretended she didn't have a sister,
>   because her sister and her good-for-nothing husband were as
>   unDursleyish as it was possible to be.

Comment: Yes, the former is grammatical, the latter is not.

Comment: **didn't met** is incorrect for at least one major reason: you always use the bare infinitive after *to do*, not a conjugated form.

Comment: *Hadn't met* is correct usage. *Didn't met* is not grammatical. It would have to be *didn't meet*. However, in this context (written in the past tense), *hadn't met* is preferred.

Comment: "...but they hadn't met for several years; in fact..." indicates that there was no meeting for some time (several years) **prior** to the narrative. COMPARE TO: "...but they didn't meet for several years *after the Potter wedding;* in fact..." indicates a span of time **since** some specific event.

Comment: Fleshed out, this could be an answer, no, @Davo?

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang - perhaps. I have read a lot of books, and I (believe that I) have a very good feel for how the language works. But I'm not always able to properly identify and explain the official rule of how and why something should be a certain way. But thank you, I will compose a proper answer for this. :)

Comment: Actually, this will help me learn the proper labels by researching them. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usage:

> ...but they **hadn't met** *for several years;* in fact...

indicates that there was no meeting *for some time (several years)* **prior to the narrative**.

The usage:

> ...but they **didn't meet** *for several years after the Potter wedding;* in fact..."

indicates that there was no meeting *for some time (several years)* **since some specific event.**

Comment: As far as I know "didn't meet" is "past simple". Am I right?

Comment: @VardanHovhannisyan Ah, you are correct. Let me edit that.

Comment: Looks good to me :)! And I notice you hadn't even needed to learn the proper labels :D (not that I think you would have needed them anyway :)).